# How to prevent main context from fail if the import context failed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I have a spring application and I need to import some contexts via bean initialization, like this:

```
<bean id="import" class="importer">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath*:config.xml">
</bean>
```

And if there are any errors while importing, program should not fail, and the main context should continue initializing.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lazy-init="true"` so that it doesn't create problem when loading the context. However, it will raise an exception when the bean is requested and it fails to import the context.

Comment: But `lazy-init="true"` can only be used with bean creation, and I need to do some custom import, which is works like default `<import resource="classpath*:config.xml"/>`, but not throw exception, when importing context failed to load

Comment: Can you explain what type of import are you talking about.

Comment: I'm importing another application context from xml configuration file. By default i can do it as i explained upper, but if imported context failes, main context will fail too and the application would not sart. I need to do my custom import, works like default, but continue loading main context if importing failed.

Comment: If IoC container fails to load the application context it will raise the exception. There is no way around.

Comment: But is there any way to override or extend IoC container, so if it fails to load some secondary importing context, it will just not load this context and continue loading other beans?

Comment: Possibly, `FactoryBean` can help you create the instance of the classes you need and handle the exception yourself. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.4/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html